# Netbeans 7.4 C++ simple hello world error build failed tried everything on the first 2 pages of google search results

Tags: c++, netbeans, compiler-construction, cygwin

```
    "/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
    make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Great Albino/Documents       /NetBeansProjects/Tutorial 1'
    cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Tutorial\.d
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Tutorial/.d
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/tutorial_1.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Great Albino/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Tutorial 1'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Tutorial 1.o.d
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Tutorial 1.o.d -o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Tutorial\ 1.o Tutorial\ 1.cpp
g++: error: 1.o.d: No such file or directory
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:68: recipe for target 'build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Tutorial 1.o' failed
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/Tutorial 1.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Great Albino/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Tutorial 1'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:60: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Great Albino/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Tutorial 1'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 330ms)

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
std::cout << "Hello World!";
return 0;
}

and 

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
cout << "Hello World!";
return 0;
}
```

tried both ways

And i changed the filemame to tutorial_1

heres some fluff because i have too much code. heres some fluff because i have too much code. heres some fluff because i have too much code. heres some fluff because i have too much code. heres some fluff because i have too much code. heres some fluff because i have too much code

I have the GCC, G++, AS, Make, GDB added in cygwin.

Im running windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a filename like 'Tutorial 1.cpp'. i.e. with an embedded space. netbeans might support it, but it'll likely confuse the build scripts no end.

I should really avoid spaces in filenames.